# Can you make non-reach melee weapon attacks while on a Huge+ mount?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, creature-size, mounted-combat, reach

Logic would say that, if you're mounted on, say, an elephant, you wouldn't be able to swing a sword at a goblin at the elephant's feet.

But is there an official rule that allows/prevents non-reach melee weapon attacks while on a Huge (or bigger) mount?

Comment: Duplicate of [Is weapon reach measured from the edge of the mount's space or the rider's?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87840/is-weapon-reach-measured-from-the-edge-of-the-mounts-space-or-the-riders) ?

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, i'd alao say that my question is a duplicate, looking at that question.

Comment: The questions appear to be at least peripherally different despite the answers being essentially the same. (Though the linked question still has an arguably wrong and outdated answer given the new ruling by Jeremy Crawford).

Answer (score 5):

## RAW - Yes

However, you are first and foremost going to be limited by your reach. A huge creature is a 3x3 square assuming you are using a grid. If you are a medium creature and you are in the center square of your mount, then you would definitely need to use a reach weapon to hit anything adjacent to your mount.

It is worth noting that Jeremy Crawford has [ruled](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/928363566163308544) and riding a mount does not change the effective size of your character:

> Being mounted doesn't change your character's size.

Jeremy Crawford also [said](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/928372757758320641) that when using a grid and miniatures you can "fit" the rider in any square occupied by the mount and that you can move around on your mount using your movement ([here](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/928366740886601728)).

Regardless of the mechanism, if your character can be positioned on the mount such that it might be within reach of your weapon RAW you should be able to hit something with a non-reach melee attack.

However, the DM may adjudicate cases where this may or may not make sense to apply or what kind of checks or (dis)advantages may be involved to attempt such things.

For example you could try roping yourself to an elephant and leaning way off the side of it allowing you to hit things with a sword or some other non-reach weapon, but as a DM I certainly would not allow this to automatically succeed and would require some checks.