# Avoiding the lance disadvantage when mounted on a large creature

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, advantage-and-disadvantage, mounted-combat, reach

This question begins the same as this question:

[Is weapon reach measured from the edge of the mount's space or the rider's?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87840/is-weapon-reach-measured-from-the-edge-of-the-mounts-space-or-the-riders)

However [Rubiksmoose's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/110673/28591) (the currently accepted answer) seems to contradict [JA Streich's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/87846/28591) and [Ilya's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/87842/28591), the other two highly-voted answers.  Plus, the highly-voted ones seem to suggest that it is kind of up to the player, or at least in favour of the player.

My question is then about how this all applies to a character wielding a lance while riding a large creature.

If the mount is right up against the enemy, can the character on the mount attack with the lance without disadvantage, because they are in fact not within 5 feet?

Comment: You should edit the relevant information (a quote or summary) from the linked question into the answer itself, in case the question is edited or moved, and to save people from having to look at another question just to understand this one.

Comment: Are you also playing on  a Grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It depends

So, a lance, of course, has the following text:

> You have disadvantage when you use a lance to attack a target within 5 feet of you

We are considering two different fixes to the (lack of) mounting rules:

1. You occupy the same space as your mount
2. You don't, but occupy grid-space your mount also occupies

(these are the fixes from what used to be the top three answers in the linked question.  The one which was the accepted answer, which was highly upvoted, is number 2; the other two which were *significantly* more highly upvoted are number 1, for different reasons)

In the first case, where the GM has decided your space is the mount's space, you are within 5' of the enemy because your mount is, so you get disadvantage.

In the second case, where the GM has decided you run around on your mount separate from it, you can be within 5' of the enemy if you want, but you certainly don't have to and thus can avoid disadvantage

Comment: Thanks that definitely will help. For what it's worth, I'm not sure I agree with your characterisation of my answer on that. I don't think I ever say or imply that you and the mount share space, I would actually argue that the rider, per RAW, sits on top of the mount in 3D space. Even if it looks like they are sharing squares on a 2D grid.